# React: How can I dynamically render images mapping through a list?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to map through an array of objects.

Each array element in `staff` in my json has an `imgUrl`:

```
{
    "home": {
        ...
        "staff": [
            {
                ...
                "imgUrl": "../Images/Jon.JPG",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is brought into my main `App.js` file with

```
import data from './data.json';
```

And passed to a component:

```
<Home data={data.home} />
```

and in Home I have:

```
let staff = this.props.data.staff.map((member, i) => {
    return (
        <Staff imgUrl={member.imgUrl} />
    );
```

and then in `Staff` I'm trying to load an image:

```
<img src={this.props.imgUrl} alt={this.props.name} />
```

However this doesn't work, the alt is displayed. I've checked that the correct string is passed to src and it is, but the image has still not loaded.
If I replace `{this.props.imgUrl}` with the actual path stored in the json, the image will load. I've been searching around this for a few hours now but haven't been able to get anywhere or been able to implement solutions other people have used for similar problems.

I used create-react-app to start this project.

EDIT: Ok I have been pretty stupid, I copied over the Images folder a while ago (had it in src, moved to public) but accessed the one in src with my path. I have since changed it to the public one it all works. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Try to use `console.log` while it gets url, it's possible that something is happening and img cannot get property properly

Comment: Check your browser console. It's possible that your code is working but the image fails to load for some other reason.

Comment: Try to replace `member.imgUrl` to `this.imgUrl`

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I've done what you asked but I just added a {console.log(this.props.imgUrl)} before and after the img element and it returns the correct string.

Comment: @Sergey I used console.log() in Staff to check, the string works fine using member.imgUrl but with this.imgUrl I get 'undefined'

Comment: May you post your project in GitHub and give us a link to orient inside? Or use projects in http://codepen.io

Comment: Yep just need a few minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're not importing the images into your JS file i.e.

```
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image
```

you should use the `public` folder

```
render() {
  // Note: this is an escape hatch and should be used sparingly!
  // Normally we recommend using `import` for getting asset URLs
  // as described in “Adding Images and Fonts” above this section.
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
}
```

See:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder

Comment: It's not about compiling. It's just like a JS code execution and it should just place a URL and browser should load it. It's not about including the image in JS for webpack. I think it's not for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Except you put the images in the public folder this wouldn't resolve however the fix is relatively simple.

```
{
 "home": {
    ...
    "staff": [
        {
            ...
            "imgUrl": require("../Images/Jon.JPG"),
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
  }
 ...
}
```